# How to link iOS app to facebook page in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to link my app to facebook page , I have used this code :

```
let facebookURL = NSURL(string: "fb://profile/turathalanbiaa")!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(facebookURL)
{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(facebookURL)
}
else
{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/turathalanbiaa")!)
}
```

---

**info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

**but** facebook app shows the user profile page **not** the page that I provided.  what did I miss ?

Comment: canyou show the output what you get

Comment: Just as a remark, you could use [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) instead of [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it should goto `facebook.com/turathalanbiaa` but it go to `facebook.com/my_profile` , will take snapshots to what I get

Comment: @AhmadF I get `use of unresolved identifier URL` , I'm using `Swift 2`

Comment: does not problem , your code is fine

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes it look fine , but the result not what I expect

Comment: but your code is fine and correct, try once `pageID` instead of `turathalanbiaa`